# Redirecting from all Ember routes

Tags: redirect, ember.js, routes, router

So, basically I am working on this app where I want to redirect users with incomplete profiles to fill it out. I know this can be done by using the afterModel hook within the router for EACH route, however, I was wondering if there's a hook that is called for ALL routes that could be used for this. This way I don't have to keep adding this logic in the afterModel for any new route I add.

EDIT:

What I ended up doing was this:

in controllers:

```
Blocks.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
currentPathDidChange: function() {
    var path = this.get('currentPath');
    window.document.title = path;
}.observes('currentPath')
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to the ApplicationRoute beforeModel/afterModel hook, it's the root of the app and always called at least once.

If you want it to happen every time they transition routes, you can observe `currentPath` in the ApplicationController and fire things there.  Ember will keep the value up to date as you change routes.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/opOxoKEf/1/edit

Comment: kingpink2k, helpful as always! Thanks. Once I can upvote, I'll go back and upvote your answers. :)

Comment: it's even easier than that, watch the console, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/opOxoKEf/1/edit

Comment: kingping2k, could you answer my newest question. I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: which one are you referring?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601885/how-to-structure-code-for-different-version-of-web-app-which-vary-slightly